# php flags not workings in the validation

Tags: php, function, validation

How do I activate the flags that are in the function? If I write `<"h1">test<"/h1">` in the comment field it will still be added in the database. The validation doesn't work.

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  $required = array('comment');
  $validate = new Pos_Validator($required);
  $validate->checkTextLength('comment', 3, 200);

  //$validate->removeTags('comment');

  $validate->useEntities('comment',false,true,true,true);

  $filtered = $validate->validateInput();
  $missing = $validate->getMissing();
  $errors = $validate->getErrors();
}

 public function useEntities($fieldname, $isArray = false, $encodeHigh = true,     $stripLow = true, $stripHigh = true)
{
    $this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldname);
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldname]['filter'] = FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS;
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldname]['flags'] = 0;
    if($isArray)
    {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldname]['flags'] |= FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY;
    }
    if($encodeHigh)
    {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldname]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH;
    }
    if($stripLow)
    {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldname]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW;
    }
    if($stripHigh)
    {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldname]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* example of using the filter function directly instead of showing us half your confusing class wrapper around it?

Comment: If you want to strip your HTML tags, you could use strip_tags(), but strip_tags() strips more than that. Most of your filter flags are destructive, if your input ist not plain ASCII.

Comment: what do you mean deceze? im using it in my question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With respect, this code depends on some elaborate software from a book that isn't part of the standard php distribution, so it's pointless to ask this community for help with it. We're just as confused with you are. Also it's not about MySQL

Comment: The code of the `validateInput()` method is missing. For me the appropriate name would be `maimInput()`